# Удаление сессии по id

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста: как удалить сессию пользователя  зная ее id в php? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Коммментарии к мануалу читайте](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-destroy.php)

```
<?php
$session_id_to_destroy = 'nill2if998vhplq9f3pj08vjb1';
// 1. Закрыть предыдущую удаляющую сессию.
if (session_id()) {
    session_commit();
}

// 2. Сохранить идентификатор удаляющей сессии
session_start();
$current_session_id = session_id();
session_commit();

// 3. Уничтожить нужную сессию.
session_id($session_id_to_destroy);
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_commit();

// 4. Вернуться к удаляющей сессии
session_id($current_session_id);
session_start();
session_commit();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё как вариант

```
unset($_SESSION['имя сессии']);
```